# SMB Not Able to Use Date Command Substitution

Tags: ubuntu, cron, logs, command-substitution, smb

```
smbclient //10.10.101.29/it -W WORKGROUP -U user --password pass -c 'put ./file_$(date +%Y_%m_%d).file ./folder/file_$(date +%Y_%m_%d).file'
```

The above does not work & gives me an error stating:
 **./file_$(date does not exist**

I have tried variables:

```
date=$(date +%Y_%m_%d)
```

This results in the same behavior, but instead I get the following message:
**./file$_{date}.file does not exist**

Is it not possible to use the variables from the Ubuntu shell in the smb command or smb subshell? Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work with double quotes like

```
smbclient //10.10.101.29/it -W WORKGROUP -U user --password pass -c "put file_$(date +%Y_%m_%d).file"
```

or

```
date=$(date +%Y_%m_%d)
smbclient //10.10.101.29/it -W WORKGROUP -U user --password pass -c "put file_${date}.file"
```

Comment: That got it!. If I had enough reputation, my upvote for you would show. Thanks for the help - I really appreciate it!